# Does LATEX produce more pages than MS Words if they have the exact same output?

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering, msword, pagestyle, number

My thesis should NOT exceed 30 pages and the nature of my research compels me to go beyond that limit. So I thought would it be the same number of pages IF I convert my latex document into MS Word? In others words, If I build them with the same margins and font size does this necessarily mean they would have the same number of pages 40 pages of LATEX=40 pages of MS Word?
It seems stupid but I am desperate.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: No, if they have the exact same output they have the exact same output.

Comment: More serious: If you're currently at 40 pages I doubt it'll be possible to reduce that to 30 without changing margins and/or font sizes. But all in all I'd think that TeX gives you more degrees of freedom to reduce page sizes, after all TeX optimizes paragraphs according to badnesses, and Word simply uses a first-fit model.

Comment: In addition to what Skillmon wrote: With pdfTeX/LuaTeX/XeTeX-based engines you have microtype-features like character protrusion, font expansion, adjustment of interword-spacing etc which could reduce the amount of space needed for printing the text. I don't know if nowadays MS Word has such features

Comment: Did you already look at the package [savetrees](https://ctan.org/pkg/savetrees)?

Comment: @UlrichDiez The interactive example of font expansion/character protrusion offered by [microtype](https://ctan.org/search?phrase=microtype) is limited to a short section (2 paragraphs early in the manual). With larger texts of shorter words, this has *some* impact, though (if used alone) not to the effect to push 40 pages into 30. [a4wide](https://ctan.org/pkg/a4wide) is an other «adjuster», but it may be received with even less welcome than word (own experience).

Comment: @AemTaibi You possibly are *too close* to the content of your written thesis, and thus got into the thought «all the things I still need to describe (which then let me pass beyond 30 pages for a third)». If possible, leave writing on the desk for a day or two, and then read it fresh minded again; this may ease to simplify the description (thus, reduction of the words needed).

Comment: @Buttonwood Of course, microtype can not tear a big hole into the problem. But when all other tricks are applied, it could probably handle the small leftover needed to avoid a 30th page break.

Comment: Joke: Just switch page-numbering from decimal to hexadecimal - 40(dec) = 28(hex) < 30(hex) . ;-)

Comment: With or without LaTeX, you can try to go a bit beyond the allowed margins, interline spacing, font size, use a narrow font type, minimal paragraph indentation, reduce paragraphs breaks, etc., and only with LateX use microptype, `\emergencystretch`  and so on  to gain a few lines, but at the end of day the  solution is rewrite your work  in a more clear, brief and concise  text.